# Data returns null in React frontend but not when queried inside GraphiQl

Tags: reactjs, graphql, mongodb-query, apollo

This is my first project using GraphQL, Apollo, MongoDB & React. I am attempting to retrieve details of an individual book using an id. I am running two separate servers - one for React and one for GraphQL with Cors utilized.

All other queries are working fine within React except this one. This query retrieves data in the GraphiQL interface but returns null when queried through my React front.  I have attempted to follow the Apollo documentation.

The `bookId` is passed through the `BookList` component when a book is clicked. The `BookDetails` component then displays details of that individual book within BookList. When I `console.log(bookId)` I can see the correct id is passed through to the BookDetails component.

Someone mentioned configuring the server in a similar post. I can no longer follow the provided link. However, all my other queries work, so I doubt this would relate to my sever?

**What GraphIQL interface returns: **

```
{ book(id:"6467a432d492e452717d765e") {
    name
    id
    genre
    author {
        id
        name
        age 
    }
  }
}
```

**data returned: **

```
{
  "data": {
    "book": {
      "name": "Name of the Wind",
      "id": "6467a432d492e452717d765e",
      "genre": "Fantasy",
      "author": {
        "id": "6467a330d492e452717d7658",
        "name": "Patrick Rothfuss",
        "age": 44
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What React returns back in the console **

```
{book: null}
book
: 
null
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

queries.js

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_BOOK = gql`
query($id:ID) {
    book (id:$id) {
      name
      id
      genre
      author {
        id
        name
        age
 
      }
    }
  }
;

export {GET_AUTHORS, GET_BOOKS, ADD_BOOK, GET_BOOK};`
```

**BookDetails.js**

```
import { useQuery} from '@apollo/client';
import { GET_BOOK } from '../queries/queries';

function BookDetails({bookId}) {

    const id = "6467a432d492e452717d765e"
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_BOOK, {variables: {bookId}});

    console.log(error)
    console.log(data)

    const displayBookDetails = () => {

        if(loading) {
          return( <div>Data is loading...</div> )
        } else if(data) {
            console.log(data)
        
            return ( 
                <div>
                    <h2>{data.name}</h2>
                    <p>{data.genre}</p>
                    <p>{data.author.name}</p>
                    <p>All books by this author</p>
                    <ul className='other-books'>
                        {data.author.books.map(item => {
                          return<li key= {item.id}>{item.name} </li>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
            

        } else {
            return (
                <div>No book selected</div>
            )
        }

    }

   
    return (
      <div id="book-details">
        <p> Output book details here </p>
        {data && <div>Yes there is data</div>}
         { data && displayBookDetails()} 
        
      </div>
    );
  }
  
export default BookDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `{variables: {bookId}}` to the query but the query expects an `id` variable. Furthermore `bookId` is `undefined` in your code.